# Libraries for building web app in python that scrapes data from web in the background

Tags: selenium, flask, scrapy

Basically I want to build a web app that can login into 3rd party sites in the **background** and scrape some data from them.

For building the web app I'm considering using Flask, whereas for the scraping part I was thinking about using Selenium - but I'm not sure if I host the web app Selenium would work properly. Would Scrapy be better suited for such a purpose?

Should I be considering something else altogether?

Comment: Do not use Scrapy, just use Selenium, it will save you so much time, I prefer you use Selenoid server by Aerokube so you do not have to worry about Selenoid browser deployments etc

Answer (score 1):

If its Flask use beautifulsoup(to load the webpage); Selenium(webbrowser) and scrapy(to **scrape** the data use Selector function in Scrapy its more effective and it will speed your process)